# Why a global variable isn't recognized?

Tags: php, object, global

I want to call for a variable defined at a some point in the code. I use global keyword but it seems variable isn't recognized. When I set variable locally it works just fine. (it is the *$title* variable, it receives value of a static function of some object)

THIS ONE WORKS:

```
class Book {
    public function represent() {
        $titles = Title::all_by_id();
        $title = $titles[$this->title_id];
        return $title->represent().'_'.$this->id;
    }
}
```

THIS ONE DOESN'T:

```
$titles = Title::all_by_id();
```

in another file

```
 class Book {
     public function represent(){
        global $titles;
        $title = $titles[$this->title_id];
        return $title->represent().'_'.$this->id;
     }
 }
```

It sends an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function represent() on a non-object in

What are possible problems here?

Comment: why are you working with static function?

Comment: When you say `$titles` outside the class its a `Variable`. when you say `$titles` inside the class its a `Property`. Class has a scope and anything inside the scope can be used by the class.

Comment: @Christian what is the problem with static function? It loads all Titles from database and put them in associative array id=>object, I prefer to use second way, with global, to avoid multiple database query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was the problem that I set the `$titles` variable in a different subcontext of the main context than where Book class was defined

I solved the problem when I changed the place where I was defining that variable, I've put it in the main context.